# Declare Function Excel Vba using shell32.dll

Tags: shell, excel, windows-shell, shellexecute, vba

Can someone tell me what is going on with the code below:

```
'Variables at top of module or some function/sub here

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

 'some function or sub routine here
```

This code shows the position of the function declare. I am not familiar with what the declare keyword is doing, nor do i understand why this is not compiling.

I got this when I was looking up ways to open tabs in internet explorer through vba, but I can't seem to get it to work.

It seems as though the compiler does not recognize this as a function, but I have seen several forum posts that use this code without it having any problems ([this one](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?524244-RESOLVED-open-several-tabs-in-internet-explorer) included).

It seems as though I may be missing a reference, or possibly the dll, but i don't see the library as a reference in the tools menu, and i don't know how to check if i have this on my machine.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: What happens when you try using it?

Comment: The code won't compile, so i haven't been able to use it yet. If i place it at the top of the module it tells me my other variables have become ambiguous, if i place it between subroutines, it tells me only comments can be placed there. I have edited my post for clarity.

Comment: It should be by itself at the top of the module, not inside a sub. If you get an error about ambiguous names then you may have declared another sub or variable with the name "ShellExecute", so you'll need to fix that.

Comment: This was not at the top of the module like you said, and i placed it there and it fixed it. I don't understand why it has to be at this place first. Any particular reason why this is the case? Perhaps you could answer this question with an explanation for anyone else who may come across this problem.

Comment: There's an article about the `Declare` statement at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165080%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An API declaration is like a regular variable declaration: it must be at the top of the module, before any Subs/Functions.